# problem with pd.wide_to_long specifications

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

| id | xx_04-Feb-94 | yyy_04-Feb-94 | z_04-Feb-94 | xx_22-Mar-94 | yyy_22-Mar-94 | z_22-Mar-94 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 456 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 789 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

with values inside the table filled out. I would like to pivot the data from wide to long. the desired output looks as follows:

| id | date | xx | yyy | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 04-Feb-94 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 22-Mar-94 |  |  |  |
| 123 | 16-Sep-94 |  |  |  |
| 456 | 04-Feb-94 |  |  |  |
| 456 | 22-Mar-94 |  |  |  |
| 456 | 16-Sep-94 |  |  |  |

I have more than 100 dates which I have stored in a dataframe or a list  called mydates
I have used the following code:

```
df_long= pd.wide_to_long(df_wide, stubnames = ['xx','yyy','z'], i='id', j = mydates, sep='_', suffix=r'\w+')
```

but it gives me errors:
"too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2"
or
"Must pass DataFrame or 2-d ndarray with boolean values only"

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.wide_to_long(
    df, stubnames=["xx", "yyy", "z"], i="id", j="date", sep="_", suffix=r".*"
)
```

Comment: so, this worked; but do you know how I can convert the date column to date format. For some reason, after the pivot command, python doesn't treat i and j i.e. the id and date columns the same as the rest. when I type df.dtypes, it only lists the data type for the other columns i.e xx yyy z

Comment: it is because `id` and `date` are index now. just add `.reset_index()` at the end of my code